# How to access data of tables inside DataConnection UWP

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp

So I connected the database (also tested the connection) work well [image]

So how can I get the data out of it ???

Inside the App.cs I ve created a connectionstring

```
        public string connectionString = "Server = DESKTOP-Q42NBTE; Database = FirstDataBase; Trusted_Connection = true";
    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get => connectionString; set => connectionString = value;
    }
```

Also created a class to hold all the datas 
Class BooksData:

```
    public class BooksData
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImageFile { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public int PublisherID { get; set; }
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
}
```

And a method for communication

```
    public ObservableCollection<BooksData> GetBooks(string connectionString)
    {
        const string GetBooksQuery = "select * from Books";
        var books = new ObservableCollection<BooksData>();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                if (conn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = GetBooksQuery;
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                var book = new BooksData();
                                book.Title = reader.GetString(0);
                                book.Price = reader.GetInt32(1);
                                book.ImageFile = reader.GetString(2);
                                book.PublisherID = reader.GetInt32(3);
                                book.AuthorID = reader.GetInt32(4);
                                book.BookID = reader.GetInt32(5);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return books;
        }
        catch (Exception eSql)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + eSql.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But nothing is working

Here is my Database Info

[image]

Comment: "But nothing is working", How it not work? Did you get any exceptions?What's the SQL server version?

Comment: no I didn't get any exception the UI just pop out without any information in the database I think I get wrong

Comment: please debug to ensure if the connection is successfully firstly, since you catch it which will not throw the actual exception and find what  exception caught. Also the sql server version thanks.

Comment: I got it, it's the firewall blocked my connection